# Variables are not set when a big image is processed by a PHP file

Tags: php, html, image

A web page I'm writing needs to load images of almost any size, the processing goes well with a lot of images I have tried but when I try to upload a 2.05MB image and nothing is uploaded (I tried other big images to figure out whether the image was the problem). I'm thinking it could be an overflown variable but I'd like to know what you think and the solution you would give to this problem.

```
<?php
        
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo-img'];
    $nombreImagen = $_FILES['input-img']['name'];
    $tipoImagen = $_FILES['input-img']['type'];
    $tamagnoImagen = $_FILES['input-img']['size'];
    $rutaDestino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/shap/imagenes"; //temporal

    /*If I do the next: */
    echo "Tipo: " . $tipoImagen . "<br>"; //the output would be "Tipo: "
    //and the rest would be empty thing which doesn't happen with small image
        
    if($tamagnoImagen<=524288000){ //about 500MB
        if($tipoImagen=="image/jpeg" || $tipoImagen=="image/jpg" || $tipoImagen=="image/png" || $tipoImagen=="image/gif" || $tipoImagen=="image/x-icon"){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['input-img']['tmp_name'], $rutaDestino . "/" .  $nombreImagen);
            if(file_exists($rutaDestino . "/" .  $nombreImagen)){
                echo "<p class='text-success'>Imagen subida con exito!</p>";
            }else{
                echo "<p class='text-danger'>Tuvimos un problema al subir la imagen. Por favor intentelo más tarde.</p>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<p class='text-danger'>No se admiten los archivos de tipo: " . $tipoImagen . "</p>";
            echo "<div class='text-danger'><p>Sólo se admiten archivos tipo: </p><ul><li>jpg</li><li>png</li><li>gif</li><li>ico</li></ul></div>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<p class='text-danger'>Archivo demasiado grande, lamentamos que nuestro limite de 500MB te detenga, algún día quitaremos este límite.</p>";
        echo "<p class='text-danger'>Si deseas que quitemos el límite puedes:</p>";
        echo "<ul class='text-primary'><li><a href='#'>Donar</a></li> <li><a href='#'>Ver un anuncio</a></li></ul>";
    }

?>

<form action="php/upload_image.php" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo de la imagen" class="form-control" name="titulo-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="select-img">
                Seleccionar imagen
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="input-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Compartir">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" value="Cancelar">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP is set to only allow files of 2MB or less to upload. In your PHP ini change the following values to suit your needs (I've set them to 32):

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

If you don't want to edit your ini, you can use ini_set():

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '32M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '32M');
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer, I tried adding the following code to my php file (I added it at the very beginning of the file):                                                                 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');                    
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');                                                                         Am I doing it correctly? Im asking because the problem persists :(                 I using Xampp if that helps....

Comment: Not all ini settings will take effect when put inside your php file with `ini_set()`. `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are two of these (see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#22264)). You will need to change these in your php.ini file.